# 3-input XOR gate use only NOR gate

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

What's the **minimum** number of NOR gate needed to build a 3-input XOR gate using **only** NOR gate?

Information I know:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic

`A XOR B = [ ( A NOR A ) NOR ( B NOR B ) ] NOR ( A NOR B )`

`A XOR B XOR C = ( A XOR B ) XOR C`

Using the above formulas, I can implement 3-input XOR with 20 NOR gates.

What I don't know:

What's the minimum number of NOR gate? Is there a simpler way to implement 3-input XOR gate?

Comment: what is `A NOR A`?

Comment: How have you tried to solve this and where are you stuck? This is not a free homework solving service.

Comment: @jsotola This is an inverter.

Comment: Did you cite the wikipedia correctly?

Answer (score -2):

A 3 bit XOR gate can be made using 10 NOR gates .
[image]

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to homework questions. Also, you need to provide a link or citation for the graphics you copied into your answer.